# How to reinterpret cast a float to an int? Is there a non-static conversion operator or user-defined assignment operator for conversion on 'this'?

Tags: c#

1.
How can I reinterpret cast a float to an int (or a double to a long)?

```
float f = 2.0f;
int i = (int)f; // causes conversion
```

I only want to copy the bit-pattern from `f` to `i`. How can this be done?

2.
The implicit and explicit operators in C# uses one intermediate object because the operator function is static

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(double s)
{
    return new MyClass(s);
} 
..
..
MyClass m = 2.2; // this code uses 'm' and one intermediate object.
```

This is fine for reference types, but for value-types which are big (say 20-30 bytes), this will cause unnecessary data copy. Is my understanding correct? And If yes, then why doesn't C# have a non-static conversion operator or user-defined assignment operator so that the conversion/assignment takes place on 'this'? If it does, whats the way to do it?

Comment: In the future please post two separate questions.

Comment: and don't write all the text in the headline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int bits to float bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237776/convert-int-bits-to-float-bits)

Answer (score 13):

Barring unsafe code - this is the fastest method I know of to perform a reinterpret:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct IntFloat
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int IntValue;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public float FloatValue;
    }
    private static float Foo(float x)
    {
        var intFloat = new IntFloat { FloatValue = x };
        var floatAsInt = intFloat.IntValue;
        ...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 12):

1: BitConverter (as sixlettervariables) is an option; as is unsafe code (which doesn't need an intermediate buffer):

```
    float f = 2.0f;
    int i;
    // perform unsafe cast (preserving raw binary)
    unsafe
    {
        float* fRef = &f;
        i = *((int*)fRef);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    // prove same answer long-hand
    byte[] raw = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
    int j = BitConverter.ToInt32(raw, 0);        
    Console.WriteLine(j);
```

2: note that you should limit the size of structs. I can't find a citation fr it, but the number "16 bytes" (max, as a recommendation) seems to stick in my mind. Above this, consider an immutable reference-type (class).

Answer (score 8):

1. The [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class can retrieve the bytes for any primitive type, which you can then use to create an int. Another option is [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) if you have large amounts of converting to do.

   ```
   float ff = 2.0f;
   int ii = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(ff), 0);

   float[] ff = new float[...];
   int[] ii = new int[ff.Length];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(ff, 0, ii, 0, ff.Length * 4); // byte-wise copy of ff into ii
   ```
2. No there is no other option given in C#, however, I think that while you're correct in the sense that there will be a copy made, any sufficiently simple implementation will have JIT optimizations done, possibly removing the need for a copy.

Comment: It's not clear that making the operator an instance operator would remove the need for the copy anyway. The question seems somewhat confused to me.

Comment: Back in '08 I'd made assumptions that the JIT would behave similar to a C++ compiler w.r.t. member methods, but I've yet to see it work like that in practice.

Answer (score 2):

This approach, while unsafe, works as a generic solution

```
static unsafe TDest ReinterpretCast<TSource, TDest>(TSource source)
{
    var tr = __makeref(source);
    TDest w = default(TDest);
    var trw = __makeref(w);
    *((IntPtr*)&trw) = *((IntPtr*)&tr);
    return __refvalue(trw, TDest);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the fastest and cleanest way to do it:

```
public static class ReinterpretCastExtensions {
   public static unsafe float AsFloat( this int n ) => *(float*)&n;
   public static unsafe int AsInt( this float n ) => *(int*)&n;
}

public static class MainClass {
   public static void Main( string[] args ) {
      Console.WriteLine( 1.0f.AsInt() );
      Console.WriteLine( 1.AsFloat() );
   }
}
```