# How to decode one Int64 back to two Int32?

Tags: c#

Previous question was to encode two `Int32` into one `Int64` [[C# - Making one Int64 from two Int32s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827252/c-making-one-int64-from-two-int32s/])

**Question**: How to decode one `Int64` back to two `Int32` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a (cheap) solution that will work for both conversions.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct UnionInt64Int32 {
    public UnionInt64Int32(Int64 value) {
        Value32H = 0; Value32L = 0;
        Value64 = value;
    }
    public UnionInt64Int32(Int32 value1, Int32 value2) {
        Value64 = 0;
        Value32H = value1; Value32L = value2;
    }
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Int64 Value64;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Int32 Value32H;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public Int32 Value32L;
}
```

An obvious drawback to this though, it's unportable. The Value32H and value32L will be reversed on different endian platforms.

Comment: That is a neat solution, but the problem with signed bits may be an issue. Not an issue if you're using UInt32/UInt64.

Comment: Although this is not an answer, I will definitely use this. Thanks.
Much simpler than having two conversions :)

Comment: I just wanted to save one extra column in DB, so this works even for signed values. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Something like this:

```
long x = ...;

int a = (int) (x & 0xffffffffL);
int b = (int) (x >> 32);
```

It's just possible that the masking in the first form is unnecessary... I can never remember the details around narrowing conversions and signed values, which is why I've included it :)

Comment: beware that >> behaviour for signed integer is undefined, and left to the compiler implementation. And a long isn't always 64 bits. Only long long is

Comment: @jyavenard: The question is about C#, not C or C++. It's all well-defined in C#.