# Convert int bits to float bits

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I'm in the process of creating a buffer that will read/write in a banner in which I can completely eradicate the problems that comes with TCP-Segmentation. The only problem I've ran into is the float variable, everything else works fine, besides for the float. I can't find any information on how to convert int32 bits into a float.

When converting a float to int bits, the following method is used (Ripped straight out of java's source code, and converted)

```
private int floatToIntBits(float value)
{
    int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0);
    if (((result & 0x7F800000) == 0x7F800000) && (result & 0x80000000) != 0)
        result = 0x7fc00000;
    return result;
}
```

However, now I need to do the opposite, unfortunately, there isn't any functions in the BitConverter class that works with float.

I can';t find much information in the JavaDocs either, not any that I can personally make use of, You can find info [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Float.java#Float.intBitsToFloat%28int%29).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vexingly, if you were using `double` and `long`, there is `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` and `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`. I have genuinely no idea why there aren't `Single` / `Int32` equivalents, as it forces you to create a pointless `byte[]` on the heap (it doesn't even let you pass in a pre-existing buffer).

If you are happy to use `unsafe` code, you can actually do it all in a simply data thunk, without any method calls or arrays:

```
public static unsafe int SingleToInt32Bits(float value) {
    return *(int*)(&value);
}
public static unsafe float Int32BitsToSingle(int value) {
    return *(float*)(&value);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as this is a client-api for Unity3D, I can't use unsafe code, I've found this solution before and Unity disallowed it. Thanks for the reply though, +1 for a simple solution.

Comment: @Christian.tucker yeah, that is annoying; I do a lot of bit work (I maintain several binary serializers and other network utility libraries), so this hurts me *a lot* when `unsafe` is not allowed

Answer (score 10):

BitConverter creates some overhead and unnecessary buffer. This solution is almost as fast as unsafe conversion:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct FloatToInt 
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]private float f;
    [FieldOffset(0)]private int i;
    public static int Convert(float value)
    {
        return new FloatToInt { f = value }.i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great technique, thanks for this

Comment: There is no need to use a `static FloatToInt` for this -- and doing so makes this unnecessarily thread-unsafe.  In `Convert(float value)` just `return new FloatToInt { f = value }.i;`  Since `FloatToInt` is a struct, doing `new FloatToInt { }` doesn't allocate anything on the heap.

Comment: Bitconverter doesn't create a buffer in .net core 7, at least.

`public static unsafe int SingleToInt32Bits(float value) => *((int*)&value);`
`public static unsafe float Int32BitsToSingle(int value) => *((float*)&value);`

Comment: @Warty It was about BitConverter.GetBytes(value). At the time there was no direct conversion methods, so you had to get bytes first.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`BitConverter.ToSingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
int i = ...;
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Targeting .NET Core we are now finally able to simply use `BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits()` and `BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle()`!

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `float` is an alias for the data type `System.Single`.

You can use the `BitConverter.ToSingle` to convert four bytes into a `float`.

Comment: I've never heard about that alias, very interesting.

Comment: Would this be the proper usage? `            byte ch1 = ReadByte();
            byte ch2 = ReadByte();
            byte ch3 = ReadByte();
            byte ch4 = ReadByte();
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4 }, 0);`

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend this if (per the question) it is in network code, though; all those darned `byte[]`. I've added some alternatives separately.

Answer (score 1):

using the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe nuget package

```
Unsafe.As<float, int>(ref value);
```

Will convert a float to an int

and

```
Unsafe.As<int, float>(ref value);
```

will convert an int to a float

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET Core 2.0 we've had a built-in API for this, [BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.int32bitstosingle):

```cs
float f = BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this support on .NET Framework 4.0+ or .NET Standard 2.0, you can use [`J2N.BitConversion.Int32BitsToSingle(i)`](https://github.com/NightOwl888/J2N/blob/main/src/J2N/BitConversion.cs#L88) from the [J2N NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/J2N/).

Full disclosure: I am the primary maintainer of J2N.