# Convert UInt64 to float

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, uint64

How can I convert this `UInt64` to a `float`?

```
UInt64 MyLongInt = 14250221004866263104;
float My4ByteFloat = MyLongInt;
Console.WriteLine(My4ByteFloat);
```

This has to do with a memory read I am performing. The value I am retrieving is an `UInt64` and corresponds to `14250221004866263104`. And I need to convert it to `float` since I know for a fact that my address is a `float`. Now when I do it with Cheat Engine it converts it correctly and gives me this result: `-7088`.
When I do it with `C#` it gives me `1425002E+19`.

Now I know that converting 8 bytes to 4 bytes is not the best thing to do and there might be some issues during the process but, since Cheat Engine is doing it and it is getting the right result, then it must be possible.

So anyone know how to convert this `UInt64` to `float`?

Edit: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int bits to float bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237776/convert-int-bits-to-float-bits)

Comment: No hope that `14250221004866263104` becomes `-7088`. Are you sure you are looking at the right numbers?

Comment: @xanatos addes 2 pictures of cheat engine

Comment: @xanatos I think there is. It is just missing a dot and some zeros since it is a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
UInt64 MyLongInt = 14250221004866263104;
float My4ByteFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(MyLongInt), 0);
Console.WriteLine(My4ByteFloat);
```

Comment: I am a lazy guy. The easiest way is the fastest. And the best for me. Well done

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here:

- You can't copy a number from a screenshot: you wrote *14250221004866263104* but in your screenshot it is *14253330148871733248*.
- `float` is a 32bits type, so a 4 byte type, like an `int`, not a 8 byte type.

Now, if we take only 32 bits we can see that it is:

```
uint myuint = 0xc5dd8000;
```

Then with:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct SingleToInt32
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float Single;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint UInt32;
}

float fl = new SingleToInt32 { UInt32 = myuint }.Single;
```