# Bitwise unpacking a long into two numbers

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am struggling to unpack my data from a long type to two numbers. Not sure where i am going wrong.

I create a unique number from two numbers by packing them into a long:

```
    public static long Squeeze(float x, float y)
    {
        return ((long)x << 32) | (long)y;
    }
```

So the long consists for 4 bytes for x then 4 bytes for y.

Then i am trying to get the numbers back out with:

```
float x = (float)(hash >> 32);
float y = (float)(hash | int.MaxValue); // this should be 1111 1111 1111 1111 i think
```

But it doesn't seem to work, `x` appears to be correct, but `y` is giving me numbers that it should not.

Also it needs to work for negative numbers too.

Example:

```
(2.0, 9.0) => Packed: 8589934601 => Unpacked: (2, 1.073742E+10)
(-1.0, -1.0) => Packed: -1 => Unpacked: (-1.0, -2147484000.0)
```

Comment: Why the coerce to floating point?

Comment: @Corey i did that because i thought it might fix the problem but it didn't :P

Comment: Note that casting `float` to `long` and `long` to `float` is performed _by value_. It does not preserve the bit pattern, as you seem to expect.

Comment: Is it possible to preserve it ? I tried doubles and it didn't let me do bitwise operations with it.

Comment: Or do i need overloads with different approachs if i use ints vs floats ? @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter) instead of casting:

```
public static long Squeeze(float x, float y)
{
    var bytes = new byte[8];
    BitConverter.GetBytes(x).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    BitConverter.GetBytes(y).CopyTo(bytes, 4);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
}
```

and

```
public static void Unpack(long value, out float x, out float y)
{
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    x = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
    y = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 4);
}
```

As long as you're not transferring the byte array out of the program, it doesn't matter whether the system uses little endian or big endian byte ordering. If you need to know, you can check [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian).

Comment: Is raw bitwise operations not doable then ? I'm worried the `ToArray()` is going to give me performance hits, i'm doing this thousands of times a frame so its performance critical and allocating is going cause problems.

Comment: @WDUK to be fair, you haven't mentioned performance until just now. I was just addressing _correctness_.

Comment: Sure i appreciate the correctness. Are you saying then that bitwise alone isn't going to achieve what i want to achieve? Since the goal was to do it via bit manipulation using bitwise operations.

Comment: @WDUK there are much faster methods than this, but the ones that I know of would require you to compile with the `unsafe` flag. And no, you can't manipulate floats using bitwise operations without losing precision.

Comment: @WDUK does your target environment have [`BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletoint32bits)? If so, that would likely be faster.

Comment: @WDUK the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27237776/1541563) may also help if you're still having performance issues. Particularly [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238358/1541563) as well as [this neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59273138/1541563). The latter might have some thread safety issues though, if that's a concern.

Answer (score 4):

You need `&` (bitwise and) instead of `|` (bitwise or) to extract by mask:

```
unchecked 
{
    ...
    float y = (float)(int)(hash & (long)uint.MaxValue)
 }
```

Comment: `0xFF FF FF FF` (`0b1111 1111 1111 1111`) is `uint.MaxValue`, not `int`

Comment: I just realised your method doesn't work for negative numbers:

`(-1.0, -1.0) => hash: -1 => unpacked (-1.0, -2147484000.0)`

Comment: How about now? Updated my answer

Comment: Ah nice, that works, how come my editor says the casts are redundant but it fixes the problem shouldn't the bits be the same regardless of the cast choice ? =/

Comment: I suspect this breaks if you try non-integer floats as input.

Comment: I've added `unchecked` scope as a second edit, this may prevent that suggestion from the editor

Comment: Oh true won't the int cast lose float information ?

Comment: @WDUK the problem is long before that (no pun intended). Casting `float` directly to `long` in the `Squeeze()` method already truncates the non-integer part.

Comment: It is losing the information during `packing`, but the question was about `unpacking`

Comment: @Renat are you suggesting that your solution works if the packing is implemented correctly? Because it doesn't.

Comment: Problem is i can't do bitwise to pack if i change it to doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Endian agnostic version of [Patrick Roberts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383283/8058709).

```
public static long PackLong(int x, int y)
{
    var bytes = new byte[8];

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        BitConverter.GetBytes(x).CopyTo(bytes, 4);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(y).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        BitConverter.GetBytes(x).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(y).CopyTo(bytes, 4);
    }


    return BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
}

public static void UnpackLong(long value, out int x, out int y)
{
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        x = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
        y = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        x = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        y = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
    }
}
```

A helper function like this can be quite misleading when Endianess is not accounted for.