# C# XOR on 2 IntPtr's

Tags: c#, xor, intptr

I am currently trying to XOR 2 IntPtr's but I struggle with it.

My Code:

```
IntPtr Ptr = IntPtr.Add(Memory.Engine, signatures.model_ambient_min) - 0x2c;
IntPtr xored = (IntPtr)0.5 ^ Ptr;
```

XOR doesn't seem to be possible with IntPtr's

I want to translate this:

```
DWORD thisPtr = (int)(dwEngineBase +  modelAmbientMin - 0x2c);
DWORD xored = *(DWORD*)&brightness ^ thisPtr;
```

to C#

Comment: What isn't working? What is your desired result?

Comment: It's not possible with IntPtr's as it seems.

Comment: What would XORing two pointers mean?

Comment: @FuseFire You can use the `+` and `-` operators, but why do you want to XOR the pointers/addresses?

Comment: Oh I might be mistaken. I want to translate this: ```DWORD thisPtr = (int)(dwEngineBase +  modelAmbientMin - 0x2c);
  DWORD xored = *(DWORD*)&brightness ^ thisPtr;``` to C#

Comment: @FuseFire Please [edit] your question to include the original source code and the current new source code you have in C#. Also add the source of the original source code and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: you're XORing the deferenced value, not the pointer itself

Comment: `DWORD` is `int`, not `IntPtr`. Translating the `*(DWORD*)&brightness` requires knowledge about what `brightness` is and why its address is casted to `DWORD*` before it's dereferenced. `0.5` that you are using could not be a result of the dereferencing because it's not a valid `DWORD` value.

Comment: brightness is a float value

Comment: So `brightness` is [interpreted as `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173133/11683), and the result of that is xored with `thisPtr`, which in turn is simply `Memory.Engine + signatures.model_ambient_min - 0x2c`.